# How to add fixed width to a chip widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to give fixed width for the chip widget like this image [image]

but chip width is changing based on label text

```
return SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
        child: ChoiceChip(
             side: BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 10, 60, 100)),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            selectedColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 10, 60, 100),
            label: Text(
              'Free Wifi',
              style: isChecked ? _filterButtonTextStyle : _g4LabelNormal,
              maxLines: 2,
            ),
            selected: isChecked,
            avatar: SvgPicture.asset(
                'assets/images/wifi.svg',
                width: _filterAmenityIcon,
                height: _filterAmenityIcon,
                color: isChecked ? _whiteColor : _filterAmenityColor),
            onSelected: (value) {
            }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Answer. Need to give size for Label not Entire Chip.

```
return ChoiceChip(
             side: BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 10, 60, 100)),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            selectedColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 10, 60, 100),
            label: SizedBox(width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
               child: Text(
                  'Free Wifi',
                  style: isChecked ? _filterButtonTextStyle : _g4LabelNormal,
                  maxLines: 2,
               )),
            selected: isChecked,
            avatar: SvgPicture.asset(
                'assets/images/wifi.svg',
                width: _filterAmenityIcon,
                height: _filterAmenityIcon,
                color: isChecked ? _whiteColor : _filterAmenityColor),
            onSelected: (value) {
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try below code :

```
Container(
  width: 120, // Se fixed width
  child: ChoiceChip(
    side: BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 10, 60, 100)),
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    selectedColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 10, 60, 100),
    label: Text(
      'Free Wifi',
      style: isChecked ? _filterButtonTextStyle : _g4LabelNormal,
      maxLines: 2,
    ),
    selected: isChecked,
    avatar: SvgPicture.asset(
      'assets/images/wifi.svg',
      width: _filterAmenityIcon,
      height: _filterAmenityIcon,
      color: isChecked ? _whiteColor : _filterAmenityColor,
    ),
    onSelected: (value) {
    
    },
  ),
)
```

Comment: Same. Still no change.